# Applying styles in react native with styled components

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I have a component, Logo, where I'm trying to apply a width and a height:

```
import styledNative from "styled-components/native";
import {Image, View} from "react-native"
import companyIcon from "../svg/companyIcon.svg";

const Logo = () => (
  <Image source={{uri: companyIcon}} />;
);

const StyledLogo = styledNative(Logo)`
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
`;

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <StyledLogo />
    </View>
  );
};
```

This leaves us with an invisible logo, with a width of 0. Styled-components docs seems to suggest using a passed in className property (https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#existing-css), however this seems to be for standard styled-components, not react-native / react-native-web implementation, because it's just not passed to my component. When I examine the passed props for Logo (by console logging them), there *is* a style object, but this doesn't appear to be anything I can use and there's not much mention of it in the styled component documentation:

```
style: Array(2)
  0: 91
  1: undefined
  length: 2
```

So I'm not really sure what to do with it. How can components be styled by styled-components?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't applying your styles to the image.

What is happening now, is that your `Logo` component is receiving those style-props, but it's not passing them through.

```
const Logo = (props) => ( // <-- containing style props
  <Image source={{uri: companyIcon}} />;
);
```

So what you would want to do is to spread your `Logo`s props over your Image, so it gets the data it needs.

```
const Logo = (props) => ( // <-- containing style props
  <Image {...props} source={{uri: companyIcon}} />;  // <-- styles now applied to Image
);
```

Or alternatively you can pass through just the style-props.

```
const Logo = (props) => ( // <-- containing style props
  <Image source={{uri: companyIcon}} style={props.style}/>;
);
```

**Edit:**
It also appears you are passing invalid styles. React Native expects the values you pass in to not have units. As such, your styles should be `width: 48;` instead, dropping the `...px`.

Comment: Thanks for answering - but the style object passed to the Logo is just a two item array, one item with a Number (91), the other item undefined. If I do this:
`export default ({style}) => {
      return <Image source={{uri: companyIcon}} style={style} />;
    };`

I just end up with a warning: "Invalid style with id `91`. Skipping ...". If I try passing all props:
`export default (props) => {
      return <Image source={{uri: canopyIcon}} {...props} />;
    };`
I end up with the same "Invalid style" warnings

Comment: Hmm. Styles can actually be an array to pass in more than one, and as far as I know, styles created with `StyleSheet` appear there as a numerical reference, rather than an object.
You should be able to use `StyleSheet.flattenStyles` to get the actual object representation of your style, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Oh, right. The styles are probably invalid cause you are passing `...px`. Your styles should just be numbers without units in RN!